# Unit testing in Xcode gives a Shell script Invocation Warning

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

When I run unit tests in Xcode GUI I receive this warning

```
Skipping tests; the iPhoneSimulator platform does not currently support application-hosted tests (TEST_HOST set).
```

[image]

Xcode doesn't execute my unit tests but I get the message that Test Succeeded. It looks like it just skips my test.

P.S. I know lot of people get this error when running Unit test from the Command Line but this happens in Xcode GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode cannot run application hosted Unit Tests.

There are workarounds for it from the developer site: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html